# Rails send_data doesn't save file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri to generate an XML file in my app. I want to save this file, and I want to display a dialog box in which the user can select the folder in which download this file. 
This is the action in my controller:

```
def download
  require 'nokogiri'

  if owner_signed_in?

   @slips = current_owner.slips

   builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|

   xml.cedolini{

     @slips.each do |slip|
       xml.cedolino{
         xml.codicecliente_ slip.client_code
         xml.data_ slip.day.to_s

         xml.ordini{
           slip.product_slips.each do |order|

             xml.ordine {
               xml.codicearticolo_ order.product_code
               xml.descrizionearticolo_ order.product_description
               xml.ammontare_ order.amount.to_s
             }
           end
         }
       }
     end
   }
   end


   file = builder.to_xml
   send_data file, :type => 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8;',  :disposition => "attachment; filename=db.xml"

  end
end
```

I have the route defined in this way:

```
  get '/dbsinc/download'
```

When I call the action from the view, it doesn't save the XML, I see a new page with the url of my action, and in the page I see the XML file rendered on the page, but it doesn't open any dialog box to save the file.
Where am I getting wrong? Thanks

Comment: What is `endit do`?

Comment: I made a mistake with copy and paste, it is just and end statement, I edited now with the correct code

Comment: It might help legibility if you fix your indentation, as well.

Comment: Ok I fixed the indentation

Comment: You don't save the file anywhere. `File.write` would be the simplest way to save it but think about what you are doing: You're asking for a maintenance problem if you continually write to different filenames and never clean them up, and you'll lack persistence if you want to serve a unique file to the user without having to regenerate it every time.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out, route: `post 'dbsinc/download'

And in my view I defined the link in this way:

```
<%= link_to 'Download ', {controller:'dbsinc', action:'download'}, method: :post %>
```

And it works, the download dialog opens when I click on the link.

Comment: Is this the solution to the problem? If so, the system will give you a timeout period then allow you to select the answer as the solution. And, if it is, please format it for readability.